# One click to site meta?

Tags: feature-request, design, meta

Right now from a main site, it takes **TWO CLICKS** to get to `http://meta.SITE.stackexchange.com/` -

## ***ONE!***

[image]

## ***TWO!***

[image]

[image]

---

Why not **ONE** click on the "Hot Meta Posts" & "Featured On Meta" -

[image]

Comment: Because one click is such a change. I don't think this would be useful

Comment: Not all sites have "Hot Meta Posts" shown everyday.... or is your suggestion just to add a link from that header to meta site?

Comment: @Portal they don't? I'm not talking about the hot network posts, I don't think I've been on a site without the meta box.